# Biztalk port/orchestration documentation

Tags: documentation, biztalk

We have a large biztalk EAI setup (+- 70 orchestrations, 200 send ports,...).  Almost none of the orchestrations/ports have direct bindings.  Every route is configured through filters.

Unfortunately, the time has come to document the integration scenario understandable to non-biztalk techies.

I wondered if there're any tools / word-excel-visio-... templates to document such a scenario.
It is not necessary to document orchestrain/map/code technical details, just the message flow.
(rcvport/location(with maps) -> orchestration(filter) -> sendport(s)(with filter, maps)

Thx;
Bart

Comment: I take it you've tried BizTalk Documenter? (http://biztalkdocumenter.codeplex.com/) - I'm not sure it will do quite what you want though.

Comment: Yes I have, but it is to technical focused.  It doesn't describe a messageflow...

Comment: Good question - I didn't find a solution myself yet and need to keep documentation up-to-date for a BTS setup about the same size (little less send ports). I tried UML-Sequence in Visio but I'm not a real UML pro so I keep getting sidetracked with all the modelling stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Business Process Modeling Notation (BPMN). I use it all the time to design and document Orchestrations.

Visit http://www.bpmn.org/documents.htm

Scroll down to Other Documents. The are stencils for Visio.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we designed a documentation style for message flows based on `UML`.

We represent the `BizTalk` applications as components, and use the `Ports` and `Interfaces` on these components to represent connection points. We then use the `Information flow` connection between these interfaces.

We use `Enterprise Architect` from Sparx Systems to create these artifacts and views. The benefit of this tool is that it uses a repository based approach, so all artifacts can  be reused for multiple views.

The downside to this appraoch is that you need to create all the views yourself. There is no easy way to  generate this data from the source code or deployed BizTalk applications (that i know off), so you will need to create this documentation by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used Visio to draw my own diagrams.  In my opinion, having done this for 10 years, you have to be creative and not follow any one set standard. And from one client to the next, I don't always do it the same way.  I'm trying to improve, but I don't think there is a "one size fits all" answer.

As with any doc, first, try to do something very high-level.  Then zoom-in on the details in the next diagrams.

What is missing in general is how to describe data flow to/from port to port.  For example, what if you debatch a file in a Receive Port?  I used standard Visio flowcharting shapes, for example cylinder for pipeline, box for Port, etc... then connected them with lines.  If you have just one map you can put that on the line.  If you have a bunch of them, then it's difficult to represent.  I try to put the map or the pipeline on the arrows.

I usually use the Cloud Symbol for sending data to other vendors or trading partners. 
Sometimes I use the Server boxes of Visio, to indicate sending data to another server within our company, or even to an FTP server or Web Server at another company.

I also show the "MessageBox" has a port.  For example, Receive Port is a box, then line to "MessageBox", then each Send that has a filter on it, comes out of that MessageBox.  (I end up drawing a new "MessageBox" typically for each flow, to keep them separate.

For orchestrations, I have used SnagIt to screen capture the doc, then annotate with captions and arrows, and text in a Word document after the picture.  (The problem is if you have wide or very complex orchestrations.)

Unfortunately, most the doc I do is not automated and not connected to the code or the bindings, so it can quickly become stale.  I've never found "BizTalkDocumenter" to be that useful.

I sometimes use Tables in Word to show the developer artifacts and how they related (maps, schemas, pipelines...), and include a verbal description/commentary for each.

I agree with HSedidin above that BPMN might be worth trying, but even that, the audience would have to learn.

There is a "Stencil" pack for BizTalk avaiable for Vizio here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Collection-of-Visio-2013-0283d5f4, but I must admit that I haven't used it yet.